# Using Windows Apps on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: dual-boot, wine, windows-10, 23.04

I was trying to use wine to launch a .exe on ubuntu but it's broken. Is there a way to add a compatibility layer outside of a virtual machine? My hardware is not the best and a VM makes the CPU run hot. Looking for up to date alternatives that don't rely on wine. Also, I'm open to dual booting, but I'm not entirely sure how to because all the tutorials I was looking at said for the target machine to be running windows as a prerequsite. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wine is that compatibility layer. Your choices are VMs, Wine, or using a different Ubuntu-compatible application.

Comment: If you want specific advice, specify the application.

Comment: Up to date solutions will be to use *native* software, ie. avoid using *foreign* software (eg. .exe on Ubuntu) that requires a virtual system or layer to convert API codes to match the running OS (ie. *your approach is resource intensive due to your chosen app & base OS not matching*).

Comment: What app? Did you look it up on winedb? Some apps require configuring Wine.

Comment: It's webkinz (nostalgia). It's not in the wine db. Not sure that there is a simple way to use it outside of a vm, since only mac os and windows are natively supported

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use playonlinux:

```
sudo apt install playonlinux
```

This software has environments available for certain software, and creates a new prefix for each one with a wine version that is compatible and the necessary windows addons/libraries/plugins necessary. You download it, then open it, choose install, and it will search for a list of programs. Once it has finished its search, type in the box what program you are trying to install. I have installed Office 2016 with this method.

What software are you trying to install? I have a few other tricks that might come in handy depending on the product.

Comment: I want to play webkinz on linux to relive my childhood haha. Using playonlinux I got an error related to python being an unmet dependency (even though I already have it installed). Because of this wine kept crashing. Would following this tutorial help or is it outdated too? https://www.gloriouseggroll.tv/how-to-get-out-of-wine-dependency-hell/

Comment: Haha I too have notstalgic memories of childhood games so I can relate. Can you give me the specific error message? It's likely an older version of python, and I can help you install it if you give me the error message. Cheers!

Comment: Oh and I can also help you with dual booting if you would like, It's not too complicated and although it is slightly beneficial to have windows installed first, it is not necessary. What size is your SSD/HDD? What percentage of that size is currently used?

Comment: Regarding the guide you linked, you definitely want to execute this command:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
followed by:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine32
and then:
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine winecfg
which will set your default wine prefix to 32 bit which that game most definitely will be.
However I have searched and it seems not many people have had luck installing the game on Linux. Still, if you provide me with the python error I may be able to help. PlayonLinux does not have it listed as a game however, but it doesn't mean it can't work.

Comment: I have searched google and it seems that not many have had success with this game on linux, but it does not mean it is impossible. However, I noticed that there is a version available on the googleplay store. Have you considered using an android emulator (much more lightweight than a full operating system VM).

Comment: Doing that last command gave me this output but everything else worked.

https://pastebin.com/hwpyJKp8

Comment: Play on linux is working but maybe setting the app to 32-bit like you said would help it run better

Comment: Yes, you are probably right about the android version. However, it doesn't have the full experience that the desktop version does.